# Is AGPLv3 reasonable for an internal analytics API server?

Tags: agpl-3.0, api

I'm developing an analytics server that companies should be able to run as-is & interact with internally via APIs. I'd like for them to be able to use this tool without having to open-source their own code (unless they modify the tool).

Example use-case would be: decide if a particular email or ip address is good or bad / pass or fail / etc. In other words, their own end users would not directly benefit from this analytics server, but the company would be able to get more info regarding their own users.

Is AGPLv3 fitting for this type of use-case?